# Working application launched from C# fails

Tags: c#, vb6

I have C# application acting as a scheduler.  It runs various applications successfully. One of these applications (VB6) fails halfway through the job.  If I execute this VB6 application directly with the exact same parameters, it completes successfully. The scheduler runs other VB6 applications successfully.  Does anybody know what could cause this?  What in the environment changes when you launch an application (VB6 exe) from within another application (C#)?  Maybe there is an expert that can point me to something to help solve this?

I am adding more logging to the VB6 application and currently the error points to a routine executing SQL commands, but I have other applications executing the same code with no problem.  At this stage I am stumped.

Comment: Hey 5ilverFox, can you share some code to us? Would be great :)

Comment: To be fair, your application isn't C#. C# was the source language, but it was compiled to IL bytecode that gets compiled to native code at runtime - running the same executable code as any other process. Any problem here would either come down to the user context (perhaps that application doesn't work correctly under the scheduled task's user context) or environment variables (a variant of the first problem in most cases). Consider how the environment is different between your different run cases.

Comment: Definitely going to be the user context. Try monitoring the user id of the 'c#' process with procmon from sysinternals to see the user context.

Comment: Try [edit]ing to post code

Answer (score 2):

The following might be different

- user account / user rights
- working directory
- environment variables

I suggest inspecting the VB6 application with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and comparing against a working version.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I have now proven (with logs) that the problem happens when sql code gets executed.  The sql code has a syntax error and the sql code was supplied by the user.  The problem is that the code is wrapped between "On error resume next" and "On error goto 0" to prevent it from failing, but it still fails.  Running it directly does not fail.  In both cases the code runs on the same machine and the same user.  Thanks for the tip.  I will use Process Explorer to try and determine the difference.  This will take a while ....

Comment: @5ilverFox: On Error Resume Next is one of the worst ideas VB6 came up with. Still interesting why it fails one time and doesn't in the other case.

Comment: I suppose validating the SQL code would be too much of a job for them.  Process Explorer revealed nothing.  I tried moving the On Error trapping to different levels, ie to the calling function and that definitely stop the failing.  So there is some relation to the number of times On Error is called and the different sub routines influence each other.

Comment: I have function A calling function B calling function C calling function B.  They have On Error statements in B & C and before they "close" the On Error statement in C, the call B with it's own On Error statements.  I did not write the code, but it looks like I will have to rewrite parts of it to reduce the number of On Error statements.  Why it does not work when called from C#, I have no idea.  Maybe some limit in the call stack.

Comment: @5ilverFox: if c# really runs the application as its own process, VB6 will get its own call stack.

Comment: @5ilverFox: can you share both, C# and VB6 executables? I could sign an NDA if needed.

Comment: I will start by sharing the last two routines in C# that calls the external programs (mostly VB6)

Comment: Thomas, I would like to share my C# code, but don't know how.  I cannot paste it in a comment, because it is too big.

Comment: @5ilverFox: you can send me some code at thomasweller[#]wellisolutions.de

Comment: Yeah, hard to read. That part of the code should be possible to edit into the question. Use the edit link below your question

Comment: Space is not enough to show code. Did you get my email?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem.  I started by rolling back the VB6 code two versions and proved that it worked.  I then added small pieces of the new code and checking every time if it still works.  I did not add back all the code (some were just cosmetic) and it is now working with the new functionality.  It has taken a LOT of hours and it will take a lot more to determine what caused the original error, so I decided to take the win, because I cannot afford more hours.